# how can hide previous and next button on pagination in bootstrap pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap paginator. this application by default display next, previous and last buttons on pagination. but i am displaying all pages in pagination. so there is no need to display next, previous and first button. is there any way to achieve this. i try as below but it still displays these buttons. Please help.

```
var options = { showFirstLast: false    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go :)

```
ul.pagination li:first-child, ul.pagination li:last-child{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Less if you import Bootstrap as less files then:

```
ul.pagination {
    > li {
        &:first-child, &:last-child {
            display:none;
        }
    }
}
```

but i recommend to use 'ol' instead of 'ul', i think a pagination is a list of ORDERED elements, not UNORDERED.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap does not restrict the HTML markup you use. You can simply exclude the next and previous buttons from the HTML.

Instead of:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Do this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```